# How to disable "You changed the date of this occurrence of 'event'. To change all the dates, open the series. Do you want to change just this one?"

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

When I move a single instance of a recurring event to a different day in Outlook (2013), I get a popup that says something like:

> You changed the date of this occurrence of "Event". To change all the
>   dates, open the series.
>
> Do you want to change just this one?

I know what I need to do if I want to change the recurring event. Is there a way to disable this popup?

Comment: Doubt there is a way to disable it. Have not been able to find anything. You may know what you need to do, but Outlook doesn't know what you know. So they programmed it to ask when there are more than one occurrence of an event.

Comment: @CharlieRB - Yeah, it looks like that is the case.  Thanks for taking a look.